# Ubuntu 18 binding window key to mouse button 08

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to bind button 8 of my mouse to "window" key using xbindkeys. I can confirm the button is working and created the ~/.xbindkeysrc fine with correct information but nothing happens. Restarted the daemon, restarted the computer etc but still no luck. Below is the xev output when the mouse button 8 is pressed

```
user@user-ThinkPad-T480:~$ xev | grep button
    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES
    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES
```

Here's my ~/.xbindkeysrc file

```
"xte 'key Super_L'"
b:8

"xte 'key Super_L'"
b:8
```

PLease shed some light guys. Thanks.

-B